# Strange performance difference between Ubuntu and Macports versions of PHP

Tags: php

After doing some profiling on a personal pet project, I'm playing around with some stupid micro-optimisations. It's largely an experiment more than anything else so the things I'm tweaking don't actually need to be tweaked. It's still an interesting exercise though.

Anyway, I've come across a strange performance difference between my installation of PHP 5.3 on OS X through Macports and on Ubuntu from apt.

It seems that the following code shows a massive speed difference between the two different versions on OS X, but only a minuscule speed difference on Ubuntu.

```
$x = array(9);

// As per BarsMonster's comment, this ensures it runs for more
// than a second in order to avoid possible kernel scheduler differences
$count = 10000000;
$s = microtime(true);
for ($i=0;$i<$count;$i++) {
    $q = is_string($x);
}
var_dump(microtime(true)-$s);

$s = microtime(true);
for ($i=0;$i<$count;$i++) {
    // This is obviously only useful if you'll never need a string 
    // with 'Array' in it here
    $q = (string)$x!='Array';
}
var_dump(microtime(true)-$s);
```

The output when running on OS X:

```
float(17.977133989334)
float(4.2555270195007)
```

The output when running on Ubuntu:

```
float(5.2112979888916)
float(3.4337821006775)
```

It doesn't surprise me to see that the figures for the hacked up cast version are pretty similar, but the is_string method is wildly different.

What can I attribute this to? If the performance varies so drastically from installation to installation for trivial type testing functions, how can I trust the results of profiling using an OS that does not match my target deployment platform?

There is no difference in the times when running with APC on or off on both Ubuntu and OS X.

Comment: I'm assuming this was run multiple times, at different periods, ie enviromental elements aren't playing much of a factor here? It does seem like an unusual difference. Is this under CLI? Can you try to compare with an installation of 5.2 on the same OSX installation?

Comment: Yep, Fanis, I made sure I ran it a zillion times and found it to be  100% reproducible on both machines. The result was the same on both machines regardless of whether it was run through CLI or apache2/mod_php. I also ran it a zillion times in both modes to verify that. I'm not sure it's going to be very easy for me to switch to 5.2 on the OS X machine as I have quite a bit of 5.3 work to do ATM and disrupting my primary dev environment is not going to be possible.

Comment: But apart from that, your two code's don't really do the same thing. Testing `is_array($x)` and `$x != 'Array' && (string) $x == 'Array'` would be way more accurate. (Because arrays aren't the only non-string types in PHP ...)

Comment: But even that isn't the same yet, because the `__toString` method of an object may return `'Array'`.

Comment: But apart from that: On my Windows 7 machine the results are nearer to the Mac one (concerning the difference between both).

Comment: @nikic: I am not concerned about the issues with the strangeness of the test I'm performing. I'm concerned about the difference between running the same script on ubuntu and mac. The test itself is not the concern.

Answer (score 1):

The Ubuntu installation was in the same PC as the OS X installation?

It may be something related to zts.

Try to configure it yourself with the same flags on both systems.
There may be options enabled by default on ubuntu which are disabled by default in Ports.

I don't know exactly which, but your phpinfo() will tell. If it does not (maybe the phpinfo does not show, maybe it just shows a blank page; then maybe one of your systems is compiling with the Susoshin patch (or something else).

Comment: The ubuntu installation runs in a virtual machine on another computer. I'll try the configure thing and see if it deals with the discrepancy. Neither machine has suhoshin.

Comment: I'd say: try to run it under the same specs, but I figure the virtual machine should have lower performance... so I'm impressed

Answer (score 0):

1. Please test for 1 second minumum, on sub-0.1 second timeframe kernel scheduler differences(and dozens of other reasons) might impact your results.
2. Check if you had any accelerators installed accidentally (APC, eAccelerator, e.t.c) - just compare phpinfo() from both instances and you will see.

Comment: I updated the question to reflect testing for more than a second as you suggest, but it didn't change the results. APC is installed on both machines - I never leave home without it. Subsequent runs of the same script on the same machine produce nearly identical results, indicating to me that the opcode cache has nothing to do with it, but I'll turn it off and run again.

Comment: There is no difference in the times when running with APC on or off on both Ubuntu and OS X

Comment: Well, does both PCs have the same CPUs with same cache size?

Comment: No, but that doesn't seem relevant considering the issue is about the relative difference between two tests on the same machine.

Comment: Did you install both and then test them? or did you install one and then test and then installe the other then test?  Also you should do multiple tests and come up with the average. and the test should be a like a 100 times or more so it's more accurate. also eliminate anything that is unusually very slow as that may be considered as a glitch and therefore can effect the outcome.

Comment: How did you install both PHP engines? Im thinking maybe some extra modules loaded. Even perhaps the compiler versions are different and well, performance is kind of picky with all these variables in hand. But I do reckon, there is quiet a bit of a difference there...